# Nested objects deserialization to a TypeScript Class

Tags: json, typescript

I have a class, for example, let's say a `Car` with the below structure.

```
@Serializable()
export default class Car {
  @JsonProperty({
    name: 'id'
  })
  private id!: string;

  @JsonProperty({
    name: 'name'
  })
  private name!: string;

  @JsonProperty({
    name: 'carOwner'
  })
  private carOwner!: Owner;
}
```

Further I have the `Owner` class.

```
@Serializable()
export default class Owner{
  @JsonProperty({
    name: 'id'
  })
  private id!: string;

  @JsonProperty({
    name: 'name'
  })
  private name!: string;

  @JsonProperty({
    name: 'address'
  })
  private address!: string;
}
```

I have an incoming JSON Object with below structure, let's call it `newCar`

```
{
  "id": "test-id",
  "name": "test-car",
  "carOwner": {
    "id": "owner-id",
    "name": "owner-name",
    "address": "owner-address",
    "gender": "owner-gender",
    "age": "owner-age",
  }
}
```

What I want to do is, deserialize the `newCar` JSON to the `Car` class. That is when I deserialize `newJson` I should get the below object, where `gender` and `age` are filtered out.

```
{
  "id": "test-id",
  "name": "test-car",
  "carOwner": {
    "id": "owner-id",
    "name": "owner-name",
    "address": "owner-address"
  }
}
```

But right now what I am getting is the original `newJson`. It seems that the library (`typescript-json-serializer`) which I am using does not deserialize nested objects, here which is `owner`.

Any input will be appreciated.

Here is the link to the package [typescript-json-serializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-json-serializer)

Comment: Maybe this helps. https://github.com/GillianPerard/typescript-json-serializer/issues/82

Is Owner marked as `Serializable`?

Comment: @tiriana Yes, Owner is marked `Serializable`. Apologies that I didn't mention it in code. I'll edit.

Comment: No worries.

And when you deserialize - do you pass the `Car` class as second argument?

`typescriptJsonSerializer.deserialize(newCar, Car);`

Comment: @tiriana I found the solution for it. Apparently I missed to pass the type `Owner` inside the `JsonProperty()` for `owner` in `Car` class.

Comment: Well, glad I "helped" :)

Comment: @tiriana Yes, thank you. I did get some insight from the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution for it. Apparently I missed to add one parameter in `JsonProperty()`.
In the `Car` class, for `carOwner` object, I had to pass type of owner.

```
@JsonProperty({
    name: 'carOwner',
    type: Owner,
})
```

The above solved the issue I was facing.